# How to set different expiration timeout for each NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, alamofire, nsurlsessionconfiguration

Is it possible to set different expiration timeout for each request?

The only way I found was to create a new NSURLSession with a different NSURLSessionConfiguration and change the `timeoutIntervalForResource`. Same thing with frameworks like Alamofire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You absolutely can do this. You can set the value directly on an `NSMutableURLRequest` which can be passed into Alamofire.

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get")!
let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
mutableURLRequest.timeoutInterval = 5.0

Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
```

---

#### UPDATE

You cannot control the `timeoutIntervalForResource` per request. The timeout interval property on `NSURLRequest` is equivalent to `timeoutIntervalForRequest` on the `NSURLSessionConfiguration`. More details [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/from-nsurlconnection-to-nsurlsession/#general).

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `timeoutInterval` is the equivalent of `NSURLSessionConfiguration` `timeoutIntervalForResource`. Is it possible to change the `timeoutIntervalForRequest` per request?

Comment: sorry I mean the other way around. `timeoutIntervalForRequest` can be set per request with `timeoutInterval `, but `timeoutIntervalForResource` which is the one I need can't

Comment: Ah ic now. From what I can tell from all the docs, this is not possible to control per request. My answer has been updated accordingly.

Comment: You can always do it with an external dictionary of dictionaries of timers, using the session and task identifier as keys, invalidating the timer when a task finishes, and canceling the task if the timer fires first.  That was the recommended approach for a long time anyway, because the timers in NSURLConnection were so quirky.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can do this-

Use this code

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] configuration] setTimeoutForResource:30];
```

You have to just change the setTimeForResource in different view controllers.

Comment: but it will affect all requests in the queue. Let's suppose I've 9 requests in the queue and then when I add the 10th I change the timeout. This change will affect all of them, which is something I don't want